# How to show a hidden div if multiple conditions apply to it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, multiple-conditions

I've hit a bit of a snag in the program that I am currently working on. After asking the last question I had I was able to complete almost the entire thing up until this point. What I'm attempting to do is instead of having to create multiple div's to get my code to work(It will work that way but I would rather cut down on the amount of code) is just using one div to show what I would like it to show. For example, here is the jfiddle for an example of what I'm attempting to do.

http://jsfiddle.net/vcq9L/

This is an example of the HTML I'm using

```
<input name="search_fields" type="radio" onclick="showtest(0)" /> Test

<div id="test0">
Test 0<p></p>
<input name="search_fields" type="radio" onclick="showtest(1)" />Test 1
<input name="search_fields" type="radio" onclick="showtest(2)" />Test 2
<input name="search_fields" type="radio" onclick="showtest(3)" />Test 3
<p></p>
</div>

<div id="test1">
Test 1<p></p>
<input name="search_fields" type="radio" onclick="showtest(4)" />One
<input name="search_fields" type="radio" onclick="showtest(4)" />Two
<p></p>
</div>

<div id="test2">
Test 2<p></p>
<input name="search_fields" type="radio" onclick="showtest(4)" />One
<input name="search_fields" type="radio" onclick="showtest(4)" />Two
<p></p>
</div>

<div id="test3">
Test 3<p></p>
<input name="search_fields" type="radio" onclick="showtest(4)" />One
<input name="search_fields" type="radio" onclick="showtest(4)" />Two
<p></p>
</div>

<div id="test4">
    Test
</div>
```

And here is the js

```
function showtest(test){
    $('[id^="test"]').hide();
    if(test >= 0){
        $('#test0').show();     
    }
    if(test === 4){
        $('#test1').show();
        $('#test2').hide();
        $('#test3').hide();
    }
    $('#test' + test).show('slow');
}
```

When you run the jfiddle how the first radio button runs down the line and displays the final test div is how I would like it to be for all of them if that makes sense. Would it be best to put the data into an array and then call on the array in js so that it displays how I would like it too or is it much simpler than that?

Comment: I do appreciate and have accepted the answer as it is in multiple parts of my code. The only issue is that it doesn't allow me to, for example, have id"test"3 stay shown when onclick="showtest(4)" but also hide test1 and 2

Comment: Khawer means that you should accept the answer via stackoverflow. That's how we reward good answers. Has nothing to do with putting the answer in your code :)

Comment: Also the link to the JFiddle just brings you to the homepage...